# Shelve Module considered as shelve.py

Tags: python, import, module, shelve

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J63U.png)

Hey, i am new in python
i am trying to import shelve module but pycharm say

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mavic\PycharmProjects\ABS-CH8\shelve.py", line 1, in 
import shelve
File "C:\Users\mavic\PycharmProjects\ABS-CH8\shelve.py", line 2, in 
namavariale = shelve.open('mydata')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'shelve' has no attribute 'open' (most likely due to a circular import)

i am trying to import shelve module not shelve.py, what is the solution?

Comment: Please upload your code, not picture.

Comment: Hi Avicena, welcome to Stack Overflow! Like yakyo said, can you provide your code a text instead of an image. You will have more answers. You can look at the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for an example of how to include your code in your question.